# C++: Adding a POD to the next location in an std::vector<char>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, char, unsigned-integer

Let's take an unsigned int as an example. So, I want to add an unsigned int to an `std::vector<char>` such that the next four bytes of the vector will be populated by the four bytes of the uint.

Now, I'd like to do it using Sharptooth's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657268/convert-built-in-types-to-vectorchar) but I have two questions:

1. How can I use this method to insert the uint starting **at the first free location of the vector** - where the `end` iterator points to.
2. I wonder if the `end` iterator is incremented when copying into a vector using `memcpy` which isn't vector's function.

If the answer of 2 is negative, what method would you recommend as the best way to accomplish this task. The other answers in the mentioned link refer to adding to the beginning of the vector.

The question refers to other PODs as well.

Comment: memcpy can be used for any target index.. but make sure you've allocated space first..

Comment: memcpy will **not** increase the end iterator. It just bulldozes over the memory location you give it, regardless wether it's yours or not. memcpy is completely unaware of any containers.

Comment: You want to use sharptooth's answer specifically, not for example sbi's answer in the question you linked? sbi's answer seems to solve both 1) and 2).

Comment: @jogojapan, isn't sbi's answer less efficient?

Comment: @Subway It _may_ be slower than `memcpy`, that's right. Well, in that case, I guess you'll have to use the `resize` function of the vector to ensure it's large enough before applying `memcpy`.

Comment: @jogojapan, thanks for answering. I have another disfavor upon sbi's answer, for it ignores endianess.

Comment: Endianness is the same issue for both methods. They'll both copy the bytes in the order stored in memory. Hence, if you use the `vector<char>` to send the bytes as a sequence over the network, the recipient may be unable to re-convert them back to integers (or other PODs). But if you don't intend to send the stream of bytes to another computer (or, for that matter, store it on disk and load it on another platform), this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the answer you linked:

```
myVector.insert(myVector.end(), begin_binary(num), end_binary(num));
```

Where the begin and end functions just cast the value you want to insert.  Doing it this way does increase the size of the vector (and its capacity, if necessary).

Comment: What about endianess? This is the (main) reason I pointed to Sharptooth's answer.

Comment: And another question, why does this answer use `reinterpret_cast` not `static_cast`?

Comment: How do you want it to work?  My answer will use the system's "native" endianness.  If you want the opposite, use `std::reverse_copy` with `std::back_inserter` similar to @43l0v3k's answer.  If you want to always use "network" byte order, you'll need conditional compilation, template specialization, or similar (see ntohl() and whatever related functions exist on your machine for the various integer widths).

Comment: You can't use `static_cast` to convert between unrelated types like int and char, hence `reinterpret_cast` being used here.

Comment: @Subway: In order to handle endianness, people usually insert a known 16-bit magic number at the beginning of a message, something like 0xAAFF. Then if the other side reads it as 0xFFAA, it will know that it needs to swap bytes from that point on. This endianness test only needs to be done once between two endpoints.

Comment: @AlexK: I think even more usual is to simply decide which endianness to use (often "network byte order" but also can be "x86 byte order because that's the most popular system").  File formats with an endian mode encoding built in seem to be used more for embedded devices like digital cameras or where multi-platform encoding speed is the most important.

Answer (score 2):

1,2

```
std::copy(begin_binary(num), end_binary(num), std::back_inserter(my_vector));
```

STL automatically manages vector size while inserting new elements.